# Oracle Connect by and Hash join

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, nested-loops, hierarchical

I have a query 1:

```
select *
from (
select 'null' parentcode, u.unititemcode childcode, null unititempartnbr, null partoid,
null proccode, null unititemtype, null qualcat, null unititemgm2, null rsncode
from wi_unititem u where
u.prodproccode='PM11' and
u.prodendtime>sysdate-10
union all
select p.unititemcode parentcode, u.unititemcode childcode, 0 unititempartnbr, p.oid partoid,
p.proccode, u.unititemtype, u.qualcat, u.unititemgm2, u.rsncode
from wi_uitempart p, wi_unititem u where
p.unititemparttype='USEDSET' and
u.prodproccode=p.proccode and
u.setid=p.setid    
) m
where m.unititemtype<>'SKID'
start with m.parentcode='null'
connect by prior m.childcode=m.parentcode
```

explain plan for query 1:

```
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 64  Bytes: 2 745  Cardinality: 9                                    
23 FILTER                               
    22 CONNECT BY WITH FILTERING                            
        9 VIEW TIPSMSY. Cost: 12  Bytes: 610  Cardinality: 2                        
            8 UNION-ALL                     
                2 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE TIPSMSY.WI_UNITITEM Cost: 4  Bytes: 29  Cardinality: 1                  
                    1 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX TIPSMSY.WI_UNITITEM_PROCCODE_ENDTIME Cost: 3  Cardinality: 1           
                7 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE TIPSMSY.WI_UNITITEM Cost: 3  Bytes: 46  Cardinality: 1                  
                    6 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 8  Bytes: 113  Cardinality: 1             
                        4 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE TIPSMSY.WI_UITEMPART Cost: 5  Bytes: 67  Cardinality: 1         
                            3 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) TIPSMSY.WI_UITEMPART_PK Cost: 4  Cardinality: 1   
                        5 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX TIPSMSY.WI_UNITITEM_SETID Cost: 2  Cardinality: 1          
        21 VIEW TIPSMSY. Cost: 64  Bytes: 2 745  Cardinality: 9                         
            20 UNION-ALL                    
                12 FILTER               
                    11 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE TIPSMSY.WI_UNITITEM Cost: 4  Bytes: 29  Cardinality: 1             
                        10 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX TIPSMSY.WI_UNITITEM_PROCCODE_ENDTIME Cost: 3  Cardinality: 1          
                19 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE TIPSMSY.WI_UNITITEM Cost: 3  Bytes: 46  Cardinality: 1                 
                    18 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 60  Bytes: 904  Cardinality: 8           
                        16 NESTED LOOPS         
                            13 CONNECT BY PUMP      
                            15 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE TIPSMSY.WI_UITEMPART Cost: 18  Bytes: 938  Cardinality: 14     
                                14 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) TIPSMSY.WI_UITEMPART_PK Cost: 4  Cardinality: 43  
                        17 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX TIPSMSY.WI_UNITITEM_SETID Cost: 2  Cardinality: 1
```

And query 2:

```
select *
from (
select 'null' parentcode, u.unititemcode childcode, null unititempartnbr, null partoid,
null proccode, null unititemtype, null qualcat, null unititemgm2, null rsncode
from wi_unititem u where
u.prodproccode='PM11' and
u.prodendtime>sysdate-20
union all
select p.unititemcode parentcode, u.unititemcode childcode, 0 unititempartnbr, p.oid partoid,
p.proccode, u.unititemtype, u.qualcat, u.unititemgm2, u.rsncode
from wi_uitempart p, wi_unititem u where
p.unititemparttype='USEDSET' and
u.prodproccode=p.proccode and
u.setid=p.setid    
) m
where m.unititemtype<>'SKID'
start with m.parentcode='null'
connect by prior m.childcode=m.parentcode
```

explain plan for query 2:

```
SELECT STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 122  Bytes: 82 655  Cardinality: 271                                    
23 FILTER                               
    22 CONNECT BY WITH FILTERING                            
        9 VIEW TIPSMSY. Cost: 70  Bytes: 80 520  Cardinality: 264                       
            8 UNION-ALL                     
                2 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE TIPSMSY.WI_UNITITEM Cost: 62  Bytes: 7 627  Cardinality: 263                
                    1 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX TIPSMSY.WI_UNITITEM_PROCCODE_ENDTIME Cost: 4  Cardinality: 263             
                7 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE TIPSMSY.WI_UNITITEM Cost: 3  Bytes: 46  Cardinality: 1                  
                    6 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 8  Bytes: 113  Cardinality: 1             
                        4 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE TIPSMSY.WI_UITEMPART Cost: 5  Bytes: 67  Cardinality: 1         
                            3 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) TIPSMSY.WI_UITEMPART_PK Cost: 4  Cardinality: 1   
                        5 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX TIPSMSY.WI_UNITITEM_SETID Cost: 2  Cardinality: 1          
        21 VIEW TIPSMSY. Cost: 122  Bytes: 82 655  Cardinality: 271                         
            20 UNION-ALL                    
                12 FILTER               
                    11 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE TIPSMSY.WI_UNITITEM Cost: 62  Bytes: 7 627  Cardinality: 263           
                        10 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX TIPSMSY.WI_UNITITEM_PROCCODE_ENDTIME Cost: 4  Cardinality: 263        
                19 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE TIPSMSY.WI_UNITITEM Cost: 3  Bytes: 46  Cardinality: 1                 
                    18 NESTED LOOPS  Cost: 60  Bytes: 904  Cardinality: 8           
                        16 HASH JOIN        
                            13 CONNECT BY PUMP      
                            15 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID TABLE TIPSMSY.WI_UITEMPART Cost: 18  Bytes: 938  Cardinality: 14     
                                14 INDEX FULL SCAN INDEX (UNIQUE) TIPSMSY.WI_UITEMPART_PK Cost: 4  Cardinality: 43  
                        17 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX TIPSMSY.WI_UNITITEM_SETID Cost: 2  Cardinality: 1
```

Query 1 contains "sysdate-10", and query 2 contains "sysdate-20", this is the only difference, Query 1 runs quite fast, and Query 2 runs very slow.

If we compare the execution plan, then the difference can be found in rows starting with 14 and 16:
Query 1 uses Nested Loop Join + Index range scan
Query 2 uses Hash Join + Index full scan

Is it possible to use execution plan of query 1 for query 2 too?

Comment: Query 2 is dealing with more data. What makes you think that Query 1's plan is the correct plan for the increased data of query 2?

Comment: Query 2 returns about 2 times more rows than Query 1. The Query 1 plan is correct, because of table WI_UITEMPART, where the index full scan take place, contains millions of such indexes. Query 1 produces only about 10000 rows, this means Query 2 produces about 20000 rows.

Comment: The first select of both queries has a column `null unititemtype`, later `where m.unititemtype<>'SKID'`. Because `NULL` is never equal nor not equal to `NULL`, none of the rows from the first query will be included in the final result, unless the start with connect by brings back thing eliminated by the `where` clause. Also, have you tried parametrizing the query so that it would be `sysdate - :bind_variable`? Run once with 10, then 20, 20 should reuse plan then. An experiment, not a solution.

Comment: Regarding NULL: you're right, but it doesn't affect to speed of execution. I've already tried to use bind variable as you said - plan is the same as for Query 2 (bad plan)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to copy the execution plan is to use the full set of outline hints.

Use these two statements to generate the explain plan with the Outline Data.  This is also the best way to generate the explain plan, for several reason described in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32723459/409172).

```
explain plan for select * from dual; --Add your real query here.
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format => '+outline'));

Plan hash value: 272002086

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |      |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| DUAL |     1 |     2 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Outline Data
-------------

  /*+
      BEGIN_OUTLINE_DATA
      FULL(@"SEL$1" "DUAL"@"SEL$1")
      OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$1")
      ALL_ROWS
      DB_VERSION('12.1.0.2')
      OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('12.1.0.2')
      IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS
      END_OUTLINE_DATA
  */
```

Use the Outline Data as a hint to guarantee the execution plan will stay the same.  Although "guarantee" might be a strong word; these undocumented hints may not work in different versions or if the query is semantically different.

```
select 
  /*+
      BEGIN_OUTLINE_DATA
      FULL(@"SEL$1" "DUAL"@"SEL$1")
      OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$1")
      ALL_ROWS
      DB_VERSION('12.1.0.2')
      OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('12.1.0.2')
      IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS
      END_OUTLINE_DATA
  */
* from dual;
```

That should work but is a bit ugly.  Ideally you want to get to the root cause of why Oracle made a bad decision - investigate estimated versus actual cardinalities, statistics, etc.  But there are lots of ways to do that and it takes a long time.  As a compromise, you may want to play with the hints and try to narrow it down to only the one or two necessary to fix the performance problem.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks a lot for answer. I've tried your way of execution plan displaying - it shows the same info as my execution plans. Could you please give some advises how the root cause of the issue can be found, or advise which hints to use (I tried USE_NL, but it was just ignored)?

Comment: Did you run the two statements as regular SQL?  Don't run them through some IDE's explain plan "tool".

Comment: Maybe try this hint: `select /*+ index(p) */ p.unititemcode parentcode ....`.  Without the full table and index definitions its hard to reproduce the plans.

Comment: Hint /*+ index(p) */ doesn't work. I can't post here full table and index definitions, due to the tables are very large (more than 100 columns) and contain 10-30 indexes. The reason of wrong plan is obviously increased amount of returned rows, but these amounts are much less than tables rowcount. I'm starting to think this behavior is some kind of oracle "internal connect by" behavior, due to results returned by recursion (look to "CONNECT BY PUMP" in the plan) are joined by Hash join. I found no hints to affect this behavoir, are there any hints that could affect to hierarchical query?

Comment: I just tried to use Outline Data hint, but no success. Plan for Query 2 has not changed.

Comment: That's odd.  Did you put the hint in the top SELECT statement?  Those hints are the same way Oracle uses outlines, there should be a way to make them work.