# function based index vs column index oracle performance

Tags: oracle, performance, indexing, query-optimization

I already have an index named **idx_MyTableColumn** on table named MyTable.
I ran a query

```
select * from MyTable where  MyTableColumn = 'AAA';
```

Then, I tried to run the explain plan for the above query, plan told me the cost of the query is 65701. No optimization needed.
Explain plan as below:
 [image]

I dropped the index idx_MyTableColumn on MyTable table.

Then, I placed a function based index named idx_UpperMyTableColumn on MyTable

```
create index idx_UpperMyTableColumn on MyTable( upper(MyTableColumn) );
```

Then,again I tried to run the explain plan for the newly created function based index query, this time total cost is 21634.
Explain plan as below:
[image]

I am so surprised to see this. Is function based index works faster then normal column based index? Or I am missing something?

Comment: Please post both the explain plans.

Comment: Both index are fresh whether column base index was created some times ago? Check [link(https://blogs.oracle.com/sysdba/entry/when_to_rebuild_index) about rebuild index.

Answer (score 2):

Function-based indexes are not generally faster than regular b-tree indexes.  The discrepancy in the results is probably caused by two issues - your IDE is not properly displaying the explain plans and table statistics need to be gathered after creating a function-based index.

Graphical SQL clients never produce reliable explain plans.  They always leave something out and never do as good a job as the simpler `explain plan for ...;` `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);`.  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32723459/409172) for a list of common problems.  In this specific case the operations are incorrect.  There is no such thing as an `INDEX` operation.  There are about a dozen different types of index access paths.  Perhaps one plan has an `INDEX FAST FULL` and the other an `INDEX RANGE SCAN`.  It wouldn't necessarily be fair to compare those two operations.

Normally index statistics are automatically generated upon creation.  But this is not true for function-based indexes, which use a virtual column on the table.  For function-based indexes the table statistics must be re-gathered for the statistics to be accurate.

Generate a new explain plan, re-gather table statistics, and compare the results again.  (And don't worry too much about the cost column in the first place.  Even though it's called the "Cost Based Optimizer" the cost is usually worthless.  It's more useful to compare things like cardinality and wall clock times.)

Answer (score 2):

The best tool for investigating the performance of a single SQL Statement is the SQL Monitor report. Contrary to what Jon Heller says, the SQL Monitor report provides much **more** information than the simple explain plan. It will provide run time statistics (eg Actual number of rows from a row source), plus information on wait activity, memory usage, bloom filter vector size and a whole set of other useful information. In fact, you can see a SQL Monitoring report live, while a query is running.
`Explain Plan`, and `dbms_xplan` will only show estimated plan and cardinalities. For many cases, this may be sufficient, but for more complex SQL or for more involved performance analysis, I highly recommend learning the SQL Monitor report.

For the question as asked, Jon is probably correct in that it's just a difference in the stats. The cost is not "worthless", in so far as it's the cost by which the optimizer will compare plans, but Jon is correct that comparing estimated vs actual cardinalites is the starting point for investigation, hence my recommendation for the SQL Monitor report

Comment: I agree the SQL Monitor report is usually the best tool for the job.  Sorry if I wasn't clear, I was referring to the way programs like TOAD and PL/SQL Developer have an "explain plan window" that is inferior to the results produced by the `DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY`.

Comment: @JonHeller. The newer version of SQL Developer will allow you generate a SQL Monitor report too, although the UI is a little convoluted. For plain execution plan, I like to use DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(), so that you get the actual plan used.